# Custom back button without any background, just an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

How do I make an Back Button from a `UINavigationBar` that doesn't have a background...just shows an image as seen on the Youtube app for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Go near to Your designer and tell them to create image as you want and put it on UIButtont, such like

```
UINavigationBar *bar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
bar.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[bar.leftBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[item release];
```

Comment: do I insert those lines in the AppDelegate?

Comment: insert these line into your viewcontroller

Comment: When I load the view I see the original back button for some seconds and then my custom..